# html_entity_decode not working as expected

Tags: php, linux, character-encoding

I am moving a PHP application to another server, and I have some issues with the character decoding:

Old server (CentOS with Plesk Panel):

```
echo htmlentities('ú'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Result &uacute;
echo html_entity_decode('&uacute', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Result ú <= expected
```

New server (Debian dedicated server, fresh install):

```
echo htmlentities('ú'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Result &uacute;    
echo html_entity_decode('&uacute', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Result Ãº <= not expected
echo html_entity_decode('&uacute', ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1'); // Result ú <= expected
```

Why is happening this? Maybe a server configuration problem?

Comment: You are sending the wrong charset specifier with your HTML output.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why the same function works as expected on one server and not on the new one.

Comment: Why are you blaming the function? **Your** HTML output contains no charset= or encoding= attribute anywhere. If you send UTF-8 text but leave the html page or http headers to claim Latin-1, then they're not rendered incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
echo htmlentities('ú', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo html_entity_decode('&uacute;', ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Comment: If I test this lines on the new server the resutl is the expected, but if I test them on the old one I get the wrong result. I need to know why I have different results on both servers.